# Build failed with xcode on iphone

Tags: ios, flutter

i have a flutter project and it can run on the android simulator, but show the "build failed" while using xcode to build, i've check the flutter doctor and all the things r fine, and the error shows like the image below, maybe it's caused by the dependencies, but i dont know how to fix, cause i'm a new user
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34EQF.png)

and i have such dependencies, works good on android simulator:
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
get: ^4.6.1
provider: ^6.0.1

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
sqflite: ^2.3.2
dynamic_color: ^1.7.0
adaptive_theme: ^3.6.0
bruno: ^3.4.2
flutter_local_notifications: ^17.0.0
logger: ^2.2.0
firebase_core: ^2.27.1
cloud_firestore: ^4.15.10
shared_preferences: ^2.2.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

tell me how to do that make the ios build succeed

Comment: Try running the `pod update` command

Comment: remove your Podfile.lock and install pods again:

rm -rf Podfile.lock (inside ios folder)
run: pod install --repo-update

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.